# WiFi-Pumpkin -'X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have installed wifi-pumpkin in my ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
but whenever i want to run it it gives me error like this

```
mahim@MyUbuntu:~/Desktop/WiFi-Pumpkin$ sudo wifi-pumpkin 
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name opentype'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x147
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x280000c
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x280000d
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x280000d
WiFi-Pumpkin Already Running.
X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
  Major opcode: 54 (X_FreePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x280000d
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 2 (X_ShmDetach)
  Resource id:  0x280000c
```

And it also gives a popup window like this
[wifi pumpkin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713uZ.png)

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

- `sudo vim /etc/environment`
- Add this `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1` to the file
- use `:wq` to save and quit

Than re-execute your `./wifi-pumpkin`

Comment: What does the `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM` variable do?

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf QT_X11_NO_MITSHM – stops Qt form using the MIT-SHM X11 extension.